# NPM INSTALL / RUN SERVE PROBLEM IN VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, npm

So this problem happens when I upload a project to VS CODE and in terminal type npm install and npm run serve. This is VUE project...

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Радна површина\Udemy\prj-cmp-01-starting-setup (2)/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Радна површина\Udemy\prj-cmp-01-starting-setup (2)\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\ivana\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-07T13_12_37_433Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\ivana\OneDrive\Радна површина\Udemy\prj-cmp-01-starting-setup (2)>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, in your project, there is a file *package.json* missing. In order to solve this, you can try these commands:

Step 1 - `npm init` - this will create the missing *package.json* file **OR** `npm init -yes` for creating a default *package.json* file

Step 2 - `npm install`

Further information about this solution, you can go to this website: https://www.cloudhadoop.com/2018/10/fix-for-error-packagejson-not-found-in.html

Answer (score 0):

How you create your vue app?

If you dont have vue-cli you run this linge in your terminal to install global vue-cli:

```
npm i -g @vue/cli
```

when cli is instaled you can run:

```
vue create my-app
```

after that you chose what you want in your app: vue 2 or 3, router or not etc...

when all is instaled you have 2 comands to do;

```
cd my-app
```

to entry in your app

```
npm run serve
```

to run serve in your app
Normally when you respect this it should works.